# Why I am getting this error in this code.I was coding for machine learning project on real estate price prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, syntax-error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOXIm.jpg)

code in jupyter notebook

I am unable to understand why it is giving error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Search for the error message online to get an understanding. Extract a [mcve] from your code to include in your question, so people here can reproduce your scenario unambiguously.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change `random_set` to `random_state`.

See the list of parameters in [the documentation for sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html).
Since you are working in Jupyter notebook there's conveniences to help you avoid such mistakes. If you started typing the first letter `r` of `random_` and **then hit tab**, you would have seen the first suggestion listed is `random_state` and you can choose it. In fact, you if had gone further and typed  first few letters of `random_` and **then hit tab**, you'd see it autocomplete with the correct syntax.